# Heroku: get error stack when an error is happening

Tags: debugging, heroku

Is there any chance we can modify Heroku's behaviour to get the error stack like I have in local?

Ex:

```
NameError in Best#search

Showing /media/augustin/Documents/Workspace/best/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml where line #29 raised:

undefined local variable or method `new_user_session_pat' for #<#<Class:0x00000002eb09b8>:0x00000004a12008>
```

Instead of:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

I know there are heroku logs, I know its certainly not recommended in production environment, but since I'm still developping, I'd be happy to have nicer messages than the logs ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time no talk, but the answer was actually very easy :

In `/config/environments/env_name.rb` (eg. production or staging), you need to set:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```

Besides, it could also be interesting to intercept the error message in production, not to display heroku's default page. It could be done like this :
http://blog.yangtheman.com/2012/10/11/user-friendly-500-and-404-pages-on-rails-3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use heroku logs:

```
$ heroku logs --app your_heroku_app_name
```

references: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: Yes, I know, but its much less comfortable than seeing what's wrong on each page.